# Clojure - call a function over and over using the result as an argument

Tags: clojure

I have a simple function that adds numbers together and multiplies them.

```
(defn add-and-multiply [x y z]
  (let [add (+ x y z) 
        mult (* x y z)] 
    (println "Add: " add) 
    (println "Mult: " mult)))

(add-and-multiply 1 1 2)
Add:  4
Mult:  2
nil
```

How would I call `add-and-multiply` again with the `x` argument now being the result of `add` (4), the `y` argument being the result of `mult` (2) and the `z` argument being the same (2).

How could I then repeat this process 100 times and then print the final values of add and mult?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would not be surprised to find that the result after 100 iterations is too large to fit into RAM. Unless I am misunderstanding the formula, this is a lot like computing `x*(x^2)*(x^4)*(x^8)`...up to `x^(2^100)`, which simplifies to `x^(2^200)`. It's actually larger because there is an adding step as well, but I think that is relatively minor compared to the iterative multiplication. 2^200 is pretty big already, but you could compute it if you needed to.

However, 2^(2^200) is tremendously vast. Obviously you need 2^200 bits of RAM, at a minimum, to hold that number without losing precision. A typical desktop computer has perhaps 16GB of RAM, which is 2^30 (a billion) * 16 gigs * 8 bits/byte = 2^37 bits of storage. You would need not just one desktop computer to store this, but 2^163 of them. Again, I cannot emphasize enough just how large a number that is. If every grain of sand on the planet were a desktop computer with 16GB of RAM, you would not be close to being able to store this number.

So, I would say you should probably figure out a different way to solve whatever your real problem is, assuming you can't afford to buy whole galaxies worth of computing power.

That said, regarding the mechanics of how to generalize `(f (f (f (f x))))` to an arbitrary number of calls to `f`, the other answers have given you a good explanation of how to use `iterate`, and will serve you well if you choose an `f` whose runtime is more manageable.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `add-and-multiply` to return the two results:

```
(defn add-and-multiply [x y z]
  (let [add (+ x y z) 
        mult (* x y z)] 
    [add mult]))
```

then you can use `iterate` to generate successive applications. Use `first` and `drop` to select the result you want e.g.

```
(first (drop 10 (iterate (fn [[x y]] (add-and-multiply x y 2)) [(bigint 1) (bigint 2)])))
```

Comment: `(first (drop n xs))` is `(nth xs n)`

Answer (score 1):

```
;; have a look at juxt
((juxt + * (fn [_ _ x] x)) 1 1 2) [4 2 2]

;; you can then use it like this:
(second (iterate (fn [v]
                   (apply (juxt + * (fn [_ _ x] x)) v)) [1 1 2])) ;; [4 2 2]

;; however it overflows quickly, so use +' *'
;; also, put it into a function
(defn add-and-multiply [times nb]
  (nth (iterate (fn [v]
                  (apply (juxt +' *' (fn [_ _ x] x)) v)) nb) times))

(add-and-multiply 10 [1 1 2]) ;; [7983075120467448500799760620188561621081118348584N 20456985749705433596250191236583540578087736309004220218432871989995224183078912N 2]
```

Comment: My laptop runs out of steam at about `35` iterations. Did you compute the required `100` iterations?

Comment: @Thumbnail See my answer. I'm fairly sure nobody has done it for the required 100 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to do this is

```
(defn compute [n]
  (let [step (fn [[x y z :as all]] [(reduce +' all) (reduce *' all) z])]
    (nth (iterate step [1 1 2]) n)))
```

This runs out of steam on my laptop at about `n = 35`.

Spelling out the computation helps a little:

```
(defn compute [n]
  (loop [x 1, y 1, z 2, n n]
    (if (zero? n)
      [x y z]
      (recur (+' x y z) (*' x y z) z (dec n)))))
```

But life is too short to wait for either of these to compute the result for `n = 100`.

---

We could pull `z` out of the computation either way, since it stays constant at `2`. It doesn't save much to do so, so I chose to stay with the question's prescription.